# How do I make my tables in mysql have a upper case

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, navicat

I want to do is make a table called `tblUser` and when I create one and refresh it it says `tbluser`. How do I make it have a upper case name in my tables can anyone help me? I'm using phpmyadmin and navicat for my database management.

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: @DanBracuk On Linux, table names are case sensitive.

Comment: One learns so much by reading these forumns.